# Guided object builder

Tags: c#, fluent-interface

Sometimes when designing a fluent-api it's important to build an object in a specific way/sequence.

I tried to create such a *guided* builder and came-up with this:

```
public class Query 
{
    public static IFrom Build() { return new Builder(); }

    public class Builder : IFrom, IWhere, ISelect, ICreate
    {
        public IWhere From() { return this; }
        public ISelect Where() { return this; }
        public ICreate Select() { return this; }

        public Query Create() { return new Query(); }
    }

    public interface IFrom { IWhere From(); }
    public interface IWhere { ISelect Where(); ICreate Select();  }
    public interface ISelect { ICreate Select(); }
    public interface ICreate { Query Create(); }
}
```

Usage:

```
var query1 = Query.Build().From().Where().Select().Create();
```

or

```
var query2 = Query.Build().From().Select().Create();
```

---

Without manual casting you are guided through the creation process so everything stays fluent. Or maybe there are better ways to suggest the *fluent* path?

Comment: @JanDotNet: Inspired by your replay to my other quesiton about creating immutable objects ;-)

Comment: That reminds me quite a bit of LINQ. Why not writing your own [Linq QueryProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252751/where-are-some-good-tutorials-on-writing-a-custom-linq-provider) instead ;)

Comment: What parameters do you plan to pass to the methods? Something like `Query.Build().From("SELECT * from TABLE").Where("FieldA > 20").Select("Field3").Create();` ?

Comment: @JanDotNet From/Where/Select might not have been the best example but it was the first thing I could think of right now where the order of operation matters ;-] anyways, an interesing article. It could be like in your example in the other answer where you need to specify all constructor parameters but without an order you could end it prematurely and skip some of them.

Comment: @JanDotNet as a matter of fact I use such a linq-like syntax to load a configuration where I say `From(this-data-source).Where(this-environment).Select(this-configuration)` but currently it is possible to say just Select without specifying the other parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the comment, it reminds me of LINQ. So, maybe it make sense to write a [Linq QueryProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252751/where-are-some-good-tutorials-on-writing-a-custom-linq-provider) to use the familiar LINQ syntax.

If that is not an option:

I would drop the method `Build()` and make the method `From` static instead. That simplifies the API.